# Visual Studio OSX sql server pre-login handsake failed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, macos, visual-studio

When I'm trying to open database connection i get following exception.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

i was written the code in visual studio 2017 in mac.

my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.114;Initial Catalog=DivaLearn;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=sqlserver;Connect Timeout=15;");
con.Open();
```

how can i get the data from table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of SQL are you using? - and what does SQL say on the matter

Comment: @BugFinder I'm using sql server 2012. in windows machine connection was successfully established. i can get the data from table. but In mac i can't.

Comment: Does your server force SSL encryption?  You may need to either get the certificate that is installed on your SQL Server and install it on your Mac (public key), or possibly add ";Encrypt=True" to your connection string.  It depends on how the server was setup.  I would reach out to your DBA's to determine what they did.

Comment: Looking around, this may actually be a bug in .Net Core.  See here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8645

Comment: Here's another link that talks about the TLS version, and them solving it by re-enabling TLS v1.  That's not an ideal solution, but may be something you can try.  Looking at the previous thread I posted, it looks more like a bug in the driver, since you can connect from Windows.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/09/an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-dbnetlibconnectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-when-connecting-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

This is because of a bug in .NET Core. Upgrade to 2.0.7 and it will all work again on Mac OSX Sierra. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22453